# Is there a way to make two while loop condition

Tags: c, if-statement, logical-operators, logical-or, logical-and

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLIMIT 1000

#define MINLIMIT 1

int main()
{int number = 0, valid=0;

    do {
        printf("Player 1, enter a number between 1 and 1000:\n");
        scanf("%d", &number);
        valid = number >= MINLIMIT || number <= MAXLIMIT;
        if (!valid) {
            printf("That number is out of range.\n");
        }
    } while (!valid);

    int guess = 0, chance = 10;
    // Allow player 2 to guess and check
    do {
        printf("Player 2, you have %d guesses remaining\n", chance);
        printf("Enter your guess:\n");
        scanf("%d", &guess);
        if (guess < number){
            printf("Too low.\n");
        } else if (guess > number) {
            printf("Too high.\n");
        } else if (guess == number){
            printf("Player 2 wins.\n");
        }
          else if (guess != number && chance == 0)
            printf("Player 1 wins.\n");
    } while (guess != number && chance > 0);
}
```

This is currently my code. I'm stucked at the last where once the user has use up their 10 chances, Player 1 wins. Is there anyway for two while loop condition to happen?

Comment: `chance = 0` is assignment and always false. You want `chance == 0` for a comparison.

Comment: Hi @AviBerger I have changed to == 0. However it still doesn't work.

Comment: `scanf("%d", ....)` is prone to undefined behavior.  Since MAXLIMIT == 1000, you can prevent that with `scanf("%4d", ...)`.  But it's safer to just stop using `scanf`.

Comment: @theslasher It is unclear how many attempts has the second player.

Comment: Then you have at least another problem. That bit of  code does look strange to me. It isn't a syntactically valid loop, & I don't understand why you are trying to use a loop rather than an if statement there. You might also want to consider bringing up your debugger once you get the code to compile. Oh, and at that point do you need to be checking the value of chance?

Comment: Please note that your last edit removed the line that updates `chance`. Edits should clarify and improve the question, add details or remove unnecessary parts, but not alter the code in such a way that could affect already posted answers. You could *add* revised code if the problem isn't yet solved.

Comment: @theslasher:  Q Is the problem resolved? There were several problems with the code you've posted, including a) chance = 0, b) you need to check the return value from "scanf()", and c) the loops don't do what you need. Q: Did my [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74198534/421195) help? What (if any) question(s) do you have about my suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For starters the logical expression

```
valid = number >= MINLIMIT || number <= MAXLIMIT;
```

is invalid. You need to use the logical AND operator instead of the logical OR operator

```
valid = number >= MINLIMIT && number <= MAXLIMIT;
```

This syntactically incorrect part with do statement

```
do {
    while (guess != number && chance = 0)
        printf("Player 1 wins. \n")
}
```

is redundant.

It is enough to write

```
if ( guess != number )
{
    printf("Player 1 wins. \n");
}
```

EDIT: After you changed your code in the question then write the if statement within the do-while loop like

```
    if (guess < number){
        printf("Too low.\n");
    } else if (guess > number) {
        printf("Too high.\n");
    } else
        printf("Player 2 wins.\n");
    }
```

And after the do-while loop write

```
    if (  guess != number )
        printf("Player 1 wins.\n");
```

Comment: Hi I have edited my code. However my else if statement still doesn't pass through when the chance == 0

Answer (score 0):

SUGGESTION:

Refactor your code:

- Store information about each player (e.g. "name" and "#/guesses") in a struct.
- Create an array of players: `struct player players[2];`
- Move your "make a guess" code into a function: `void guess(int number, struct player * player)`.
- Whenever you call "guess()", simply check if the #/guesses for that player has been exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

I won't address the errors in the posted code(s) because the details of this question keeps changing.

> Is there anyway for two while loop condition to happen?

Of course we can write suitable conditions to end the `do while` loops, but it seems to me that it would be more simple to `break` out when the second player guesses the number and print the winner only after.

```
int chance = 10;
do {
    printf("Player 2, you have %d guesses remaining\n", chance);
    printf("Enter your guess:\n");
    int guess = 0;
    scanf("%d", &guess);
    if (guess < number){
        printf("%d is too low.\n", guess);
    } else if (guess > number) {
        printf("%d is too high.\n", guess);
    } else {                                // No need to check equality.
        printf("%d is correct\n", guess);
        break;                              // <-- Exit the loop.
    }
    --chance;                               // Don't forget to update this.
} while ( chance > 0 );
 
if ( chance == 0 ) {
    printf("Player 1 wins.\n");
} else {                                    
    printf("Player 2 wins.\n");
}
```